# Term for putting someone else's name on one's work?

Tags: single-word-requests

This is the "Later Letters of Paul" effect, also seen in historic Chinese philosophical writings. One uses the name of a famous or canonical figure to lend credence or divine attribution to one's own writing. One want's one's ideas accepted more than one wants to credit.

Sort of the inverse of plagiarism.

What is the term for this?

Comment: I’d call that ***forgery***

Comment: As in Han Shan: http://www.poetryintranslation.com/PITBR/Chinese/HanShan.htm whose works may span the entire Tang Dynasty (618-907) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanshan_%28poet%29 This is more meme-ish than forgery. Attribution in this case was by others.

Comment: Reminds me of the time I was at school (aged about 16) and an especially creatively literate member of my form produced a *Book of Bob*. Now *Bob* was pronounced to rhyme with *Job*, in the Old Testament. Sadly I have long forgotten the content of the *Book of Bob*, but from what I recall it was unlikely to have achieved canonical status!

Comment: Like when everyone used Weird Al's name for their lame parodies?

Comment: "Not everything attributed to Einstein was actually said by Einstein." --- Confucious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Such texts are called *pseudepigrapha*; the adjective form *pseudepigraphic* is a little more common.

Comment: ***Pseudepigraphy***
     
:  the ascription of false names of authors to works. 
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pseudepigraphy

Comment: Maybe auto-pseudoepigrapha in this case

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Jim. The correct word is "forgery". "Pseudepigraph", "fallacious co-authorship" or (specifically with reference to the "later letters of Paul") "deutero-Pauline" are all euphemisms.

Comment: What does "forgery" mean? Can you provide some reference please.

Comment: Do you not know the English word "forgery"? Perhaps look it up in any dictionary?

Comment: That is what you should do, and link the definition to your question for clarity and helpfulness to users.

Comment: So, is *The Autobiography of Alice B. Toklas* a forgery??

Comment: @HotLicks. No, it is a literary fiction. "Forgery" implies that there is an intention of deceit.

Comment: So, how do you define "intention of deceit"?  Most of the Judeo-Christian Bible was not written by those who are claimed to be the authors.  It was common practice to write in another's voice back in those days.

Comment: @HotLicks Why don't we discuss this in the "Biblical hermeneutics" room? It is not a language question.

Comment: I was just using the Bible as an example.  The authorship of anything written prior to maybe 1200 AD is suspect, and even Shakespeare's work several hundred years later than that has been legitimately questioned.  It's only when oral tradition began to be written down and published (ie, post-Gutenberg) that authorship became something to be concerned with, and "forgery" or "plagiarism" became an issue.  (Besides, the OP first raised the Bible issue, but you didn't suggest that his question be moved to "Biblical hermeneutics".)

Comment: @HotLicks. I strongly contest the claim that "the authorship of anything written prior to maybe 1200 AD is suspect". The works of Greek and Roman authors like (for example) Plato, Aristotle, Sophocles, Cicero etc etc. have been thoroughly scrutinised and their authenticity is not doubted by any professional scholars.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps "creation of **apocryphal** documents".

*The adjective "apocryphal" applies to written works, that are of unknown or questionable  authorship, of doubtful authenticity or spurious.*

I am not totally satisfied by this proposal, because texts are said apocryphal by the readers a long time after their writing. I didn't remember having seen this word used for the production of the text.

Answer (score 0):

I would call it "a fallacious co-authorship" or "co-authorship fallacy"

> - [fallacy](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fallacy) - a deceptive, misleading, or false notion, belief, etc

"I shouldn't be telling you this, but he is using the late Professor Clyne's name only to enhance his paper's appeal.  It's a clear case of a fallacious co-authorship."

Answer (score 0):

There are two words to choose from, "forgery" or "pseudepigrapha."

The word forgery is used when there is criminal intent and the intent removes the rights of someone else.  Recent examples of forgeries were the Hitler diaries and the biography of Howard Hughes.  In both of those cases, the creators were trying to gain money.

The word pseudepigrapha is used for people who create religious documents and use the name and authority of others to give credence to the document.

With pseudepigrapha there is not criminal intent, as the people doing this kind of activity usually see themselves as inspired by deities, spirits or deceased people.  It is difficult, if not wrong, to include writers of biblical or Chinese material in the same category as the desperate con artist who forges a signature on a check or creates a document from Shakespeare and tries to sell it to make money.  Indeed, if there had been a court case in 300 AD about such documents, the accused would say that they had been divinely inspired, and that would have been considered a completely valid defense that would have been investigated based on the person's past behavior.

Did the person create the documents and then try to sell them to accumulate wealth?  Did they use them to start their own religion and collect money or deceive others or assume positions of power?

The word pseudepigrapha has a neutral feeling.  Forgery does not; it is definitely negative.

I disagree with the person who says that pseudepigrapha is a euphemism for forgery.

Comment: My Greek dictionary defines "pseudos" as "lie, falsehood, fraud, deceit". Hardly conductive of "a neutral feeling".

Comment: @fdb so those are the only definitions?  So someone who uses a pseudonym is a liar and deceiver and trying to commit fraud?

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking of the 'with the other person's permission or -blessing'-term (the way we assume most of the Psalms were written 'by King David,' the Ecclesiastes 'by King Solomon,' the popular English-translation 'by King James,' etc.)

Ghost-writing, maybe?

Comment: You really think King James wrote the King James Bible? Does anyone over the age of 8 think that?

Comment: We 'trust' that it was written by "scholars & translators under his command." The same way "The Art of the Deal" was 'by' Donald J. Trump (tho the actual 'writing' was done primarily by Tony Schwartz)